# System.AccessViolationException when running ActiveX function from another class

Tags: c#, exception, access-violation

I have these classes:

Form1.cs

Server.cs

Now when I do in Server.cs

```
form1.startCapture("C:\\test.mp4");
```

Then in Form1.cs

```
public void startCapture(String filename)
    {
       short result = this.axVideoCap1.Start();
    }
```

I get then a `System.AccessViolationException`

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException was unhandled.
Message = An attempt was made to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
Source = mscorlib
Stack Trace:
    at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember (String membername, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32 [] aWrapperTypes, Message & msgData)
    at VIDEOCAPLib._DVideoCap.Start ()
    at AxVIDEOCAPLib.AxVideoCap.Start ()
...
```

How can I solve this error?

```
public void startCapture(String filename)
    {

            this.axVideoCap1.CaptureVideo = this.captureVideoCheckBox.Checked;
            this.axVideoCap1.CaptureAudio = this.captureAudioCheckBox.Checked;

            this.axVideoCap1.ShowPreview = this.showPreviewCheckBox.Checked;
            this.axVideoCap1.UseVideoCompressor = this.useVideoCapCheckBox.Checked;
            this.axVideoCap1.UseAudioCompressor = this.useAudioCapCheckBox.Checked;

            this.axVideoCap1.CaptureMode = true;
            this.axVideoCap1.CaptureFileName = filename;

            this.axVideoCap1.SyncMode = 1;

            short result = this.axVideoCap1.Start();

            switch (result)
            {
                case -1:
                    MessageBox.Show("Capture Failure,Video, Audio Compressor not correct or capture file opening");
                    return;
                case -2:
                    MessageBox.Show("Capture file not found");
                    return;
            }

            this.previewButton.Enabled = false;
            this.captureButton.Enabled = false;
            this.stopButton.Enabled = true;

    }
```

Comment: Does this happen consistently or intermittently? Is this in Debug, Release or both?

Comment: You could maybe try enabling additional debugging options in Visual Studio to see if you can get more information on what's going on. Untick "Enable Just My Code" in the debugger options, and enable breaking when Win32, C++, and COM+ exceptions are thrown in debugger exceptions. May not do any good but it might get you some more info.

Comment: Where are these options in Visual C# 2010 Express? But I think that doesnt help at all because I can not open the ActiveX file (ocx) or recompile it.

Comment: In regular Visual Studio they're under the Debug entry in the menu as Options and Exceptions, but I'm not actually sure if they're there in Express. This may reveal nothing new, that is a definite possibility, but it's worth trying even though you don't have access to the code of the ocx. Right now you're just seeing the .NET error, there should be an error in the ActiveX control that might have more information.

Comment: Well I do not see it there in Express 2010

Comment: You didn't post any code that showed how you configured the capture device.  Assuming that you didn't write any, seeing the native code bomb isn't unexpected.

Comment: see my question above, i have updated it, do you mean this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, I have run an infinite loop in Form1.
Form1 started Server and Server accessed Form1.
Now I created Start.cs that starts Server and Form1 in a second thread.

Needed some Invoke Callbacks